# Meteor: "ReferenceError: module is not defined" after installing package

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I created meteor package which contains [ZiggeoSDK](https://github.com/Ziggeo/ZiggeoNodeSdk) api to integrate ziggeo into my meteor app. After installing this package it is giving error:

> ReferenceError: module is not defined

[Ziggeo](https://github.com/Ziggeo/ZiggeoNodeSdk) is Node Server SDK repository. And package contains **`ziggeo-sdk.min.js`** file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is located at the line #11 in https://github.com/Ziggeo/ZiggeoNodeSdk/blob/master/ziggeo-sdk.js

This project uses Node.js modules. Check the `require()` functions too, they load other npm dependencies such as `crypto` or `http`.

You need to ask the owner for the npm package or create one yourself https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules. Once the packages is ready, load it in Meteor using `meteorhacks:npm`.

Comment: I have included **crypto**,  **http**, **https** and **querystring** npm packages in my app and also installed **meteorhacks:npm** but it still giving me same error.

Comment: Can you show an example of your newly created npm package?